# How to send a bunch of files from PC to phone over bluetooth with a single prompt?

Tags: bluetooth

I have paired my Window phone to Windows 10 PC. Over Bluetooth, I want to share a bunch of file between the two without per-file prompt to accept, actually when sending from PC to phone. Currently, I choose a bunch of files -> Send to>Bluetooth and then choose my paired phone in the list and click send. But, then I am prompted in the phone to accept or ignore the send request for every file from the said group of files. My question is how can I receive the whole file group via a single accept/ignore prompt?

Answer (score 4):

Zip your files using 8-zip and send the archive via bluetooth
 You may also try `easy transfer`

Comment: Zipping the files is definitely the smartest way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, but I was thinking of transferring without zipping.

Comment: thats not the problem you face in wp ...its just how bluetooth security works.....